# Activity starts with onResume but next onPause

Tags: android

I have a strange behavior of Activity in complicated legacy code.
In LoginActivity I want to start some `PromotionActivity` but just after `onResume` it goes to `onPause`.
As this app has some `ActivityUtils` in one of its numerous libraries - I used another approach:
I called one default `PublicActivity` and passed a fragment there.
It looks like

```
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("fragmentName", PromotionFragment.class.getName());
        ActivityUtils.showActivity(activity, PublicActivity.class, params);
```

And all is shown without problems.
To understand why this works, I copied `PublicActivity` from a library to the main folder as a `PublicActivity2` and tried to launch it but failed again. I did different changes, even extended `PublicActivity2` from `PublicActivity`

```
    public class PublicActivity2 extends PublicActivity {}

    ActivityUtils.showActivity(activity, PublicActivity2.class, params);
```

but again failed.

How is it possible that `PublicActivity` is shown without problems but `PublicActivity2` which is extended from `PublicActivity` and used in the same `showActivity` method - only goes to `onResume` and immediately goes to `onPause`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. As it's complicated legacy code with numerous libraries I didn't notice that there is some `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in one of them which listen lifecycle of activities and compare every launched activity with a list of permitted ones. So, I found that list, added my activity and all works fine.

I didn't find it quickly because it was passed from a library to main app as another interface which extends needed one, luckily searching through the app with a word `Lifecycle` I found `getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Analytics().getActivityLifecycleCallbacks())`
So, for this weird situation when your activity immediately finishes after launching without any visible reason - my advice is to look for this `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`